# Codeigniter search doesn't give the right results

Tags: codeigniter

I coded a search function and used:

```
    $this->db->like('title', $uri,'BOTH');
```

Now if the title was to be: "Förfest" searching for: "ör" returns the correct array though "förfest" or "Förfest" doesn't. Anyone know why it doesn't?

the search query is first urlencoded (with Javascript) then urldecoded (with PHP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself. Problem was that i mixed `$this->db->like` and `$this->db->where` in the same function which resulted in only one being used.